# React state changing when pushing nested object

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to add/push a javascript object (let's call this 'session') to this.state.sessions.

I've tried this two ways:
1) Concat'ing the new session

```
this.setState({sessions: this.state.sessions.concat(session)});
```

2) Using React's immutability helpers

```
var newState = React.addons.update(this.state, {
            sessions : {
                $push : [session]
            }
        });
this.setState(newState);
```

While the shallow data (e.g. `sessions[i].location`) is added correctly, the problem is that all prior session's scope is now set to the new session.scope. In the picture link below you can see that the first session's scope values (`sessions[0].scope`) were overwritten by the second session's scope values (`sessions[1].scope`). How do I ensure that when I add a new session, prior session's values aren't affected?

[App state picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Av72I.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this has little to do with react, and the problem might be that the object in `sessions[0].scope` is copied by reference. That `scope` object might be reference shared between the old and new session values.

Comment: I'm marking this as the answer. Although I haven't solved the problem on my original codebase, I created a simpler app (still with child components) and scope updates as expected.

Answer (score 1):

Since `sessions` is an array, I would've done the following:

```
addSession = (newSession) => {
  let tempArray = this.state.sessions.slice();
  tempArray.push(newSession);
  this.setState({sessions: tempArray});
}
```

The above creates a shallow copy of the `sessions` array and puts it in a temporary variable. Next, it pushes the new session into the array and once that's done we overwrite the `this.state.sessions` with the new variable.

Comment: Thanks Chris, I gave your suggestion a go but alas the same issue persisted but I noted the following oddity: I set a breakpoint after `let tempArray = this.state.sessions.slice();`. I added two sessions, one without scope `sessions[0].scope = []` and one with scope `sessions[1].scope = [{id: 1, ...}]`. What's strange is that tempArray already has applied the second session's scope to the first sessions scope i.e. `session[0].scope==session[1].scope.